# Python: delete all space and '\n' in string

Tags: python

I cannot delete space and '\n' in the string. The code is here:

```
text = '''(ROOT
  (SINV
    (PP (IN in)
      (PP (IN between)'''

text.replace(' ', '')
print text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method call solution would be next:

```
text = '''(ROOT
  (SINV
    (PP (IN in)
      (PP (IN between)'''


text = text.translate(None, ' \n\t')
print text
```

***NOTE:*** 
Just wan't to point your attention to moment that **string are immutable** and you cannot mutate string and than work with mutated value, you have to re-assign string to itself as in code above: `text = text.translate(None, ' \n\t')`.

**Good Luck !**

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign `text.replace()` to something. Strings are immutable; this method call does *not* change `text`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your whitespace requirements are, but this seems best:

```
>>> text = ' '.join(text.split())
'(ROOT (SINV (PP (IN in) (PP (IN between)'
```

Also, to kill all whitespace

```
text = ''.join(text.split())
```

Or to not overwrite `text`

```
new_text = ''.join(text.split())
```

`.split()`, by default, splits the string on each sequence of **any whitespace** characters.

```
>>> "(SINV\n    (PP ...".split()
["(SINV", "(PP", "..."]
```

The `.join()` method joins a list of strings using a given string:

```
>>> ''.join("(SINV\n    (PP ...".split())
"(SINV(PP..."
```

If you don't want to remove some spaces you can simply re-add them:

```
>>> ''.join(text.split()).replace("(IN", "(IN ")
'(ROOT(SINV(PP(IN in)(PP(IN between)'
```

Comment: IMHO, this is the most Pythonic answer. However, it _does_ assume that the OP is wanting to eliminate all forms of whitespace... but that's probably a valid assumption. :)

Comment: Thanks. I think most of the answers assume that... I'll make some small edits to change that.

Comment: I don't think you need to change your code, just explicitly mention that it kills all whitespace, not just `' '` and `'\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression for this:

```
import re

text = '''(ROOT
  (SINV
    (PP (IN in)
      (PP (IN between)'''

print re.sub('\s', '', text)
```

It will give you output:

```
(ROOT(SINV(PP(INin)(PP(INbetween)
```

One key thing to mention that, strings are immutable object. So the operation done in `text` won't change it. you have to assign it to a new string. As in,

```
text = re.sub('\s', '', text)
```

This will assign a new string to the `text` variable.

Answer (score 0):

To do it with one round of mutation instead of two, use `str.translate` (and remember to assign the result):

```
# Python 2:
text = text.translate(None, ' \n')

# Python 3:
spacedeleter = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys(' \n'))  # Create this only once

text = text.translate(spacedeleter)  # Do this as often as you need, reusing same spacedeleter
```